# Avoid manually creating folders first to move files within them

Tags: batch

I have some files, for example

```
the punisher return.cbr
the punisher new adventure.cbr
undiscovered country america.cbr
undiscovered country canada.cbr
```

I need to move files in this way

```
the punisher
     |
     +--- the punisher return.cbr
     +--- the punisher new adventure.cbr

undiscovered country
     |
     +--- undiscovered country america.cbr
     +--- undiscovered country canada.cbr
```

I test this script

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD /B /O-N 2^>nul') do if exist "%%I*.cbr" move /Y "%%I*.cbr" "%%I\"
endlocal
```

but it works only if before I create manually `the punisher` and `undiscovered country` folders **before** to run script.
I need to avoid manually creating folders to move files

Answer (score 1):

Best solution (there are many):

You can use `RoboCopy` with the `/MOV` parameter and it will create the directory for you.

Example: `RoboCopy c:\FromHere\SomeDir c:\ToHereEvenThoughItDoesntExist\SomeOtherDir "%%I" /MOV`

Comment: mm .. no files are moved. I only have .cbr files, there are no folders that the script can use to compare folder names with those of cbr files. In my script example I had created folders before manually but I can't just use `/ MOV parameter` If first the filenames are not compared to each other to create the folder in they will be moved.

Answer (score 0):

Add the
[mkdir command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mkdir)
to the script:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD /B /O-N 2^>nul') do (
  mkdir "%%I"
  if exist "%%I*.cbr" move /Y "%%I*.cbr" "%%I\"
)
endlocal
```

The `enableextensions` option will make `mkdir` ignore an
existing folder without error (see [setlocal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setlocal)).

Comment: I test it but it doesn't work, nothing happens, seems that `mkdir %%I` is no sufficient because  `the punisher` and `undiscovered country` folders are not created and no files are moved in their respective folders

Comment: I only have .cbr files, there are no folders that the script can use to compare the folder names with those of the cbr files

Comment: Nice answer @harrymc .. it was my first thought but I figured robocopy would simplify the block.   You are the guy I love to hate. :)

Comment: @user3520363: Should have been: `mkdir "%%I"`.

Comment: @harrymc no, it doesn't work. I try to edit with this code but is not perfect. `@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%I in (*.pdf) do (

   set "file=%%I"
   for %%J in ("!file: =\!") do set "folder=!file: %%~nxJ=!"

   mkdir "!folder!" 2>NUL
   move /Y "!file!" "!folder!"
   echo "!file!" moved to "!folder!"

)`

Comment: script doesn't work in this situation, take 3 filenames `the punisher day`, `the punisher new adventure`, `the punisher new adventure now` --> script create 3 different folders when it should be create only *one* folder called `the punisher new adventure`. because you count different files that share the same 4 adjacent words. The other file `the punisher day`, on the other hand, should not be moved

Comment: another example where script doesn't work: take 2 files, for example a file called `the punisher new adventure` and `the punisher day`. Script create wrongly two different folders. but it would be correct if, instead, both files were moved to a folder called `the punisher` because both files share the same 2-adjacent words "the punisher"

Comment: I just added the missing command in your script that you asked about - I didn't fix errors in the script itself, as you said that was working well.